# Choose between abstract class and interface

Tags: class, interface, abstract-class, abstract

Among my two processes' functionality, there is a common function to merge files. I need not going to insist any of the processes to have some methods as interface does. And, also the two processes are independent. So, is it fine I just go with an Abstract class and have the implementation in that abstract class itself? Also I do not need any abstract method.

Comment: Could u pl suggest some answer and downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance is used when there is `IS-A` relation between subclass and the base class. I don't think it is the case here. You didn't specify the language, but from your profile I guess you use Java. So if you use an Abstract Class you won't be able to inherit from other, more appropriate class in the future.

Instead of inheritance you can use **composition**. Which means that you create a regular file merging class which has this method to merge files. And in classes where you want to have this functionality you just instantiate this new file merging class. It lets you inherit from other class in the future.

If you want to inform the world that those classes can merge files (to use polymorphism), and you use Java 8 you can create `default` method inside an interface and implement this interface without override this default method. But I think composition will be better in this case.